# Android webview copy link issue

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm loading webview into my android app, there is option in webview is copy link option, which is working fine desktop chrome browser and mobile chrome browser. The problem is copy link not working in android app. I'm getting the following issue while coping the link.**Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gm, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0.ERROR registryMFE-clipboard.js-copyTextToClipboard Async: Could not copy text.**Can any one help me out from this issue. Thanks is advance. I have added following permissions in manifest ,but it didn't work. My expectation is i want to copy link from webview from my android app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CLIPBOARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CLIPBOARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CLIPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CLIPS"/>
```